# Passing a Datatable From One Form to Another Form

Tags: c#, sql

I have a form1 and form2.  Form2 is opened from form1, it has a dgv after filling it, it's copied to a datatable on a click button, and form2 is closed or visible = false.  I passed the datatable to form1 but it's giving me a null reference.  Here is my code in form2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            perclothesdescriptionDT = new DataTable();

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView3.Columns)
            {
                perclothesdescriptionDT.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText);
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dRow = perclothesdescriptionDT.NewRow();
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
                }
                perclothesdescriptionDT.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
                perclothesdescriptionDT.Rows.Add(dRow);
            }
            this.Visible = false;

        }

        public DataTable mydt
        {
            get
            {
                return perclothesdescriptionDT;
            }
        }
```

In form1:

```
form2= new Form2();

                cmd1.CommandText = "insert into [dbo].[personClothesDesc](upperPart, lowerPart, belt, socks, shoes, differentSigns) values (@upperPart, @lowerPart, @belt, @socks, @shoes, @differentSigns)";
                        for (int i = 0; i < form2.mydt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upperPart", form2.mydt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString());
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lowerPart", form2.mydt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString());
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@belt", form2.mydt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString());
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@socks", form2.mydt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString());
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shoes", form2.mydt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString());
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@differentSigns", form2.mydt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString());
                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
```

Comment: That doesn't work that way. You can't initialize a completely new form instance and expect that it contains all the field values that the real form has. Instead you have to store the reference to `form2` in `form1`, f.e. as class field and remove the line `form2= new Form2();`

Comment: You are trying to read the mydt sooner than it is being initialized and filled with data. Define in the form2 an Action "OnDataSaved" or as you wish, call this action in the buttonclick event in the form 2 and subscribe to this action in the form1, right after the init of the form2, and execute the SQL command within a function (could be anonymous) attached to the action subscription.

Comment: can u give me an example of the class please